# converting np matrix and its indices to two lists

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have the following matrix.

```
data = np.matrix([[0,0.5,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6], [0,2,3,4,5,6],[0,2.2,3.5,4.4,5.5,6.5]])
```

I want to create two lists that contain each element from matrix and its corresponding index as strings.
my expected output is as follow:

```
list1 = [0,0.5,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0,2,3,4,5,6,0,2.2,3.5,4.4,5.5,6.5]
list2 = ['0-0','0-1','0-2','0-3','0-4','0-5',
         '1-0','1-1','1-2','1-3','1-4','1-5',
         '2-0','2-1','2-2','2-3','2-4','2-5']
```

Can anyone advise on it?
if possible, I want to create a function for above-mentioned process.

Thanks,

zep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over elements -

```
def createlist(data):
    ls1=[]
    ls2=[]
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        for j in range(data.shape[1]):
            ls1.append(data[i, j])
            ls2.append(str(i)+ "-" + str(j))
    return ls1, ls2
```

Call this function with your matrix-

```
createlist(data)
```

Comment: Thanks Aritesh. This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

For a `numpy` array, you could do as follows:

```
data = np.array([[0,0.5,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6], [0,2,3,4,5,6],[0,2.2,3.5,4.4,5.5,6.5]])
list1 = data.ravel().tolist()
# [0.0, 0.5, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 0.0, 2.2, 3.5, 4.4, 5.5, 6.5]
```

You could use a generator to iterate over the different lengths of the sublists:

```
g = (range(len(i)) for i in data)
```

Build the list of coordinates with a  *list comprehension*  and use string formatting to obtain the desired output:

```
list2 = [f'{x}-{y}' for x in range(len(data)) for y in next(g)]
#['0-0', '0-1', '0-2', '0-3', '0-4', '0-5', '1-0', '1-1', '1-2',
# '1-3', '1-4', '1-5', '2-0', '2-1', '2-2', '2-3', '2-4', '2-5']
```

---

And another alternative is to use [`scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html):

```
from scipy.sparse import  csr_matrix
list1 = sm.toarray().ravel().tolist()
list2 = list(zip(*sm.nonzero()))
# [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), 
# (1, 5), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]
```

Comment: Thanks Yatu for the advice.
How can i remove the parentheses and comma and replace with - in list 2.

Comment: Yes True! Updated the answer

Comment: @Zephyr try now, there was sometging wrong. Let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks Yatu. When I print list 2, i have only three elements in it.

Comment: Yes but I've updated the solution @Zephyr, please check again. Also added a simpler and much more efficient way using  `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice by using scipy. I could use this as alternate solution

Comment: How abt if I used this the for loop.i.e every loop will generate 5by5 matrix and I like to append it and later to create a dataframe. I did it by appending to a dataframe but every row I got is a list of each generation.

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure what you mean. You could consider asking another question for this and I'll be happy to help :-)

Comment: Thanks I will post it soon

Comment: i just posted it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54576302/how-to-transform-dataframe-that-contains-list-in-every-row-of-each-column

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do that with NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.matrix([[  0, 0.5, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6],
                  [  0,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6],
                  [  0, 2.2, 3.5, 4.4, 5.5, 6.5]])
ind = np.indices(data.shape).astype(str)
list1 = data.ravel().tolist()[0]
list2 = np.char.add(np.char.add(ind[0], '-'), ind[1]).ravel().tolist()
print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[0.0, 0.5, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 0.0, 2.2, 3.5, 4.4, 5.5, 6.5]
['0-0', '0-1', '0-2', '0-3', '0-4', '0-5', '1-0', '1-1', '1-2', '1-3', '1-4', '1-5', '2-0', '2-1', '2-2', '2-3', '2-4', '2-5']
```

Comment: HI Jdehesa. Thanks for your help. I could use as alternate solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use the answer above with this minor change  -

```
list2 = ['{}-{}'.format(x,y) for x in range(len(data)) for y in [len(i) for i in data]
```