# how to transform dataframe that contains list in every row of each column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transform

I have the following `dataframe` which is one of the output from for loop.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['Score'] = [['0-0','1-1','2-2'],['0-0','1-1','2-2']]
df ['value'] =[[0.08,0.1,0.15],[0.07,0.12,0.06]]
df ['Team'] = ['A','B']
```

I want to transform each element of list of each row to each element of a column.
The following is the expected output.

[image]

Can anyone help me how to transform it?

Thanks,

Zep

Comment: So the sublist in both score and value always have the same length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try of unstacking index, once after applying `pd.Series` on each list of dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['Score'] = [['0-0','1-1','2-2'],['0-0','1-1','2-2']]
df ['value'] =[[0.08,0.1,0.15],[0.07,0.12,0.06]]    

df.stack().apply(pd.Series).ffill(1).unstack(level=0).T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Out:

```
    Score   value   Team
0   0-0     0.08    A
1   0-0     0.07    B
2   1-1     0.1     A
3   1-1     0.12    B
4   2-2     0.15    A
5   2-2     0.06    B
```

Comment: How abt if i have third column which contains one element in each row? I have edited my post to add in the third column.

Comment: Hi @Zephyr  incorporated the change : )

Comment: Thanks Kiran, Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use [np.concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) :

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

x = [['0-0','1-1','2-2'],['0-0','1-1','2-2']]
y = [[0.08,0.1,0.15],[0.07,0.12,0.06]]
z = ['A','B']
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['Score'] = np.concatenate(x)
df ['value'] = np.concatenate(y)
df['Team'] = np.repeat(z, len(df)/len(z))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Score  value Team                                                                                                                          
0   0-0   0.08    A                                                                                                                          
1   1-1   0.10    A                                                                                                                          
2   2-2   0.15    A                                                                                                                          
3   0-0   0.07    B                                                                                                                          
4   1-1   0.12    B                                                                                                                          
5   2-2   0.06    B
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed out one part in my question and i just added in that.
Can you please advise?

Comment: @Zephyr check now

Comment: Thanks Akshay . Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to flatten the ists, you can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain
score = list(chain(*[['0-0','1-1','2-2'],['0-0','1-1','2-2']]))
value = list(chain(*[[0.08,0.1,0.15],[0.07,0.12,0.06]]))

pd.DataFrame({'score':score, 'value':value})

Score  value
0   0-0   0.08
1   1-1   0.10
2   2-2   0.15
3   0-0   0.07
4   1-1   0.12
5   2-2   0.06
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed out one part in my question and i just added in that. Can you please advise?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the input:

```
from itertools import chain

import pandas as pd

data = [['0-0','1-1','2-2'],['0-0','1-1','2-2']]
values = [[0.08,0.1,0.15],[0.07,0.12,0.06]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(chain.from_iterable(data), chain.from_iterable(values))), columns=['score', 'value'])
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  score  value
0   0-0   0.08
1   1-1   0.10
2   2-2   0.15
3   0-0   0.07
4   1-1   0.12
5   2-2   0.06
```

As an alternative you could use [np.ravel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [['0-0', '1-1', '2-2'], ['0-0', '1-1', '2-2']]
values = [[0.08, 0.1, 0.15], [0.07, 0.12, 0.06]]

df = pd.DataFrame({'score': np.array(data).ravel(), 'value': np.array(values).ravel()})
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed out one part in my question and i just added in that. Can you please advise?